# Can a Mac running Bootcamp access External Hard drives?

Tags: hard-drive, windows, disk-utility, bootcamp, partition

I tried connecting my external harddrive to my computer while booted in Bootcamp, but it wouldn't recognize the drive. I'm pretty sure this is because it was formatted for Mac computers. If I partition part of the drive and format it in exFat, will I be able to use that formatted partition within Bootcamp?

Answer (score 1):

If you installed the Windows Support Software, then Windows should be able to recognize `Mac OS Extended (Journaled)` formatted volumes. AFAIK, Windows can not recognize APFS volumes without third party software. If an external HDD contains a `ExFAT` formatted partition, then any version of Windows running on a Mac can access the volume. Although, older versions of Windows may need a to have an update installed. Here, I assume the external HDD is using a Master Boot Record (MBR) partition table or GUID Partition Table (GPT).

> Note: There are newer Macs running Windows that can access APFS containers for the purpose of selecting the system to use to start up your computer.